# let user create their own instances of a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, vector

I want to make it so a user of my Record creating program can create their own records. what is the best way to tackle this?

can i use an array or vector for the variable name?

```
 int RecU[100]; 

 class Record 
   {...};

 int main()
   {
   Record RecU[1]; 
   }
```

i tried it, and my program is crashing, so im not sure if it is possible.

Comment: You need to initialize each record in the array before you can use it: Record[0] = new Record(); var firstRecord = RecU.First();

Comment: @Holystream: They're not pointers.

Comment: What do you mean "crashing" in specific?  Is this the code you were using?  Exactly what do you mean by "user", or "creating their own records"?

Comment: Woops, hahaha.  I was thinking C# program.  My bad.  I should have looked at C++ tag :)

Comment: @David T. : Says stack around RecU is corrupt. and i mean the create theyre own variables using the Class data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want client code to be able to instantiate `Record` at will, all you have to do is ensure that at least one constructor is available to them (or a factory method).  Normally this is the case.  If you declare your class like this:

```
class Record 
{
};
```

...then there's nothing to prevent client code from instantiating it.  They can simply do this:

```
int main()
{
  Record my_record;
}
```

In your OP, it looked like you were trying to create an array of 100 `Record`s.  You do that like this:

```
class Record 
{
};

static const unsigned num_records = 100;

Record the_records[num_records];

int main()
{
  for( unsigned i = 0; i < num_records; ++i )
    Record& that_record = the_records[i];  // 'that_record' is a ref to one of the records
}
```

Comment: Better yet, you create a `std::vector<Record>`.

Comment: @David, yes I was going to mention that, but forgot while I was typing!

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that you have two definitions of `RecU`, which have nothing to do with one another.  There's the global one, and there's the one defined in `main()`, which hides the global one.

Comment: i cant beleive i didnt see that, i keep forgetting that classes are data types, so then how would you do it?